# Indent code in Dreamweaver in windows 7

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver 6 on Windows 7. How can I automatically indent selected lines of code?

Comment: Most IDE's that I've used allow you to highlight text, right-click, and choose "increase indent". Sometimes there's a button for it. I can't imagine DW not having something similar.

Here's a helpful resource:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7be0a.html

Comment: by indent I mean format the text automatically to a style like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style and not just "increase" the indent level by 1 for all the selected lines

Comment: Glad you found your answer; I don't personally use Dreamweaver, I use Emerald Editor and it automatically indents based on the syntax and programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I found the solution: select the lines you want, then on the toolbar on the left of the code window click on **Format Source Code**, then **Apply Source Formatting to Selection**

Answer (score -1):

you could configure the format of the indentation that you like.. in the same place you have "Code Format Configuration", it makes it look the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the selection of code.
Either hit `<Tab>` to indent or
`<Shift><Tab>` to outdent